# Sonar Jenkins plugin - How does Sonar use JDK during analysis

Tags: sonarqube

I am curious as to how Sonar Jenkins plugin uses JDK during Sonar analysis. I am running Sonar plugin off of Maven in Jenkins. In Sonar > Advanced, I see the option for JDK Installation. Is it better to just inherit from the job itself or should I define a new one? Since I am getting memory issues, such as java heap space errors, would changing my JDK installation to a different version help?

Answer (score 1):

The JDK that you select for the SonarQube post-job/step will be the one used to run the analysis - i.e. the one that is supposed to be set for your JAVA_HOME env property when you run a manual analysis.

You can inherit the one from the current job or select another one if you have troubles with the inherited one. This feature gives you all the flexibility you need.